# Concatenate if there's a value

Tags: excel

I have a table with an ID column and 6 other value columns:

```
A    B      C      D      E      F      G
ID   Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5   Col6
001  123    456    789
002  901    234    567    890    123    456
```

I'm looking for a formula that will concatenate the ID with what ever columns have values, separate by dashes (in this example).

ie.

```
=CONCATENATE(A2,"-",B2,"-",C2,"-",D2,"-",E2,"-",F2,"-",G2)
```

Only, I don't want to put dashes next to cells that don't have any value in it.

The desired output should look like this

```
001-123-456-789
002-901-234-567-890-123-456
```

With the formula I used, it looks like this:

```
001-123-456-789---
002-901-234-567-890-123-456
```

Comment: If you are in Excel 2016 you can use the new [TEXTJOIN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) function: `=TEXTJOIN("-", True, A2:G2)` In an older version you could make a UDF, or use a bunch of `IF()` formulas inside your concatenation.

Comment: I'm on Office Excel 2010. It didn't have the textjoin function :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For examples :

```
=IF(A2<>"","-"&A2,"")&IF(B2<>"","-"&B2,"")&IF(C2<>"","-"&C2,"")&IF(D2<>"","-"&D2,"")&IF(F2<>"","-"&F2,"")&IF(G2<>"","-"&G2,"")
```

Comment: Long, but it does the trick. Thanks ^. I didn't think about using &

Comment: Otherwise you can make VBA function for have a short function to apply => It implies to have a macro excel
`Function ConcatenateRange(ConcatRange As Range) As String
  For Each n In ConcatRange : nn = IIf(n = "", nn & "", nn & n & "/"): Next
  ConcatenateRange= Left(nn, Len(nn) - 1)
End Function`